# Multiple display connector combo adapter to VGA

Tags: video, vga

I have a [crash cart adapter](http://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/USB-Crash-Cart-Adapter~NOTECONS02X) with a VGA input.

I need support for:

- DVI-I (full size required, mini would be nice)
- HDMI (full size [A] required, C and D would be nice)
- DisplayPort (full size and mini [mini displayport covers thunderbolt] required, micro would be nice)

I'm looking for an adapter that takes these as input and converts to VGA output, with all these built into one just to minimize the number of things I need to carry around. Ideally the configuration would be a female VGA output port, then male cables for all the other types sticking out so I don't need to carry a set of cables around either.

Things I don't care about:

- It's OK if it has other connectors in addition to those listed above.
- I do not care about size or weight, to an extent. It must be reasonably portable, but it's more important to minimize the *number* of things I carry around rather than the amount of space they take up.

Does a combined adapter like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of products:

- [China 3-in-1 DisplayPort Male to HDMI DVI VGA Female Adapter Cable on Global Sources](http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Mini-DisplayPort/p/sm/1155971964.htm#1155971964)
- [Amazon.com: CableDeconn Multiport 4-in-1 HDMI to Hdmi/dvi/vga Adapter Cable with Audio Output Converter (black): Electronics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0768B7S49)
- [HDMI to VGA Kit - Monoprice.com](https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011410&p_id=11566&seq=1&format=2)